# Netlogo Landuse Change modeling creating iterations

Tags: iteration, netlogo, modeling

I'm using netlogo for a school project. 
This is the first time that I'm using netlogo and I'm running into some problems.

For example I want to calculate a patch "willingness to change" based on is they are with enough fellow patches according to a senario. 
I now wrote this:

```
Ask  patches [

    if count patches with [pcolor = 64] > Senario1 [ set willingtochangeN True ]
    if count patches with [pcolor = 14] > Senario2 [ set willingtochangeL True ]
    if count patches with [pcolor = 45] > Senario3 [ set willingtochangeA True ]
    if count patches with [pcolor = 35] > Senario4 [ set willingtochangeB True ]
    if count patches with [pcolor = 135] > Senario5 [ set willingtochangeI True ]
```

But i would like to do it according to an iteration, 
So that I can put Willingness to change to [patches own]
And than do something like:

```
list [ 
(land-use 1) (land-use 2) (land-use 3)]
foreach
ask [
if count patches > senarioX set willingnesstochange true ]
```

But then for senario it has to take senario1 for land-use 1 and senario2 for land-use 2 etc.

This is my code until now:

```
extensions [ gis ]


Patches-own
  [ Land-use                ;; Wat kind og landusetype a patch has
    Willingstochange        ;; If true a patch would like to change
    atractivenesstochangein ;; if a patch type is attractive to change in <1 = yess
    ]


globals
  [ 
      Senario1N             ;; the count of patches senario 1 describes
      Senario1L
      Senario1A
      Senario1B
      Senario1I
      land-use-map          ;; The land use map
      ]


to setup                    ;; The setup is divided into four procedures
  clear-all
  setup-constants
  setup-patches
  update-display
  load-gis
  reset-ticks
end

 to load-gis               ;;load the maps
  clear-all
  set land-use-map gis:load-dataset "a_LANDUSE_cellsize5.asc"     ;;loads the land use map
  gis:set-world-envelope-ds gis:envelope-of land-use-map          ;;sets the envelope of the world to match that of the GIS dataset
end


to setup-constants
  set Senario1N 2350 ;; the count of patches senario 1 describes
  set Senario1L 847
  set Senario1A 27330
  set Senario1B 1625
  set Senario1I 264
end


to setup-patches
  gis:apply-raster land-use-map land-use                         ;;patches in the land-use-map have a specific land-use now

  list of patches [ (land-use 1) (land-use 2) (land-use 3) (land-use 4) (land-use 6)  ]
    foreach 
    [ count patches > senarioN set WillingtoChange True
    ]                                    
    set atractivenesstochangein foreach 
    [ count patches / senarioN  
    ]
end



to update-display
  ask patches
  [
    if land-use = 1 [ set pcolor Green ]   ; Green = Nature           ;; patches have a certain color now
    if land-use = 2 [ set pcolor red ]     ; Dark red = Leisure
    if land-use = 3 [ set pcolor yellow ]  ; Yellow = Agriculture
    if land-use = 4 [ set pcolor brown ]   ; brouwn = Buildup
    if land-use = 5 [ set pcolor grey ]    ; grey = roads
    if land-use = 6 [ set pcolor pink ]    ; pink = industry
    if land-use = 7 [ set pcolor blue ]    ; Blue = water
    ]
end
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468584/how-to-match-a-value-of-a-list-of-numbers-to-item-from-a-list-of-names-in-netlog for something that may help to match scenarios to landuse values. What do you want to happen if (for example) the first two conditions are true and the other three conditions are not true? Is the patch willing to change if any of the > is true? Or does the patch need several to be true?

Comment: Thanks a lot! that was indeed helpful!